# Laravel search query replaces ID value with ID for related model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, inertiajs

Given the following model

```php
class WorkHours extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'date',
        'hours',
        'reason',
        'comments',
        'approved'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function approver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'approver_id');
    }

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }
}
```

in my controller method,

```php
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        return Inertia::render('WorkHours/Index', [
            'workHours' => WorkHours::query()
                ->when(Request::input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                    $query
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'work_hours.user_id')
                        ->where('users.last_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('users.first_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('users.member_number', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->paginate(20)
                ->withQueryString()
                ->through(fn ($wh) => [
                    'id' => $wh->id,
                    'hours' => $wh->hours,
                    'date' => $wh->date,
                    'reason' => $wh->reason,
                    'comments' => $wh->comments,
                    'area' => $wh->area,
                    'approver' => $wh->approver,
                    'user' => $wh->user
                ]),
                'filters' => Request::only(['search'])
        ]);
    }
```

when I just first load this page with no `search` value, the data is fine. However, if there is a search value, the `$wh->id` value is not the id of the  `WorkHours` record, but is the `id` of the `User` record instead.

I do a similar thing in other controllers, such as `UserController`, where it works fine.

```
    public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Users/Index', [
            'users' => User::query()
                ->when(Request::input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                    $query->where('last_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('member_number', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->paginate(20)
                ->withQueryString()
                ->through(fn ($user) => [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'member_number' => $user->member_number,
                    'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'status' => $user->status
            ]),
            'filters' => Request::only(['search'])
        ]);
    }
```

As you can see, the only difference is that when it works, I don't have the `join()`, although, I don't see why that alone would cause the `$wh->id` to be improperly replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's strange, too. But in this case, it's better to use withWhereHas:

```
return Inertia::render('WorkHours/Index', [
    'workHours' => WorkHours::query()
        ->when(Request::input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
            $query->withWhereHas('users', function($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('last_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                    ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                    ->orWhere('member_number', 'like', "%{$search}%");
            });
         })
        ->paginate(20)
        ->withQueryString()
        ->through(fn ($wh) => [
            'id' => $wh->id,
            'hours' => $wh->hours,
            'date' => $wh->date,
            'reason' => $wh->reason,
            'comments' => $wh->comments,
            'area' => $wh->area,
            'approver' => $wh->approver,
            'user' => $wh->user
        ]),
    'filters' => Request::only(['search'])
]);
```